# Which one is more secure to use? uuid, binascii.hexlify(os.urandom()) or random.SystemRandom()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, random, sequence

I want to create unique `<client-key>` and `<client-secret>` for the users who registers themselves for the service.

So, I was searching for the same and came up with these options:

- [**uuid**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID)
- **binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(x))**
- [**random.SystemRandom()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random.systemrandom#random.SystemRandom)

It's a silly question but I want to know that which implementation is more secure to use (with proper explanation)? Why? And what are the advantages of using it over others?

> **Note:**
>
> AFAIK, **`random.SystemRandom()`** uses **`os.urandom(x)`**. So comparison is mainly between **`uuid`** and **`random.SystemRandom()`**.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1)

```
import random
temp = random.SystemRandom()
random_seq = ''.join(temp.choice(CHARACTER_SET) for x in range(x))
>>> 'wkdnP3EWxtEQWnB5XhqgNOr5RKL533vO7A40hsin'
```

2)

```
import uuid
str(uuid.uuid4())
>>> 'f26155d6-fa3d-4206-8e48-afe15f26048b'
```

I'm not sure about the solution. So, any help would be appreciated.

**P.S.**
It'd be great if any solution is available for both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: A g/uuid is designed to be *unique* not *random*.  If you want something random generate from urandom.

Comment: @AlexK.That makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not make any difference, *all* are of them use `os.urandom` both in Python 3 and 2. `uuid4` just [instantiates a new `UUID` object by passing in `16` random bytes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/uuid.py#L600) to it:

```
def uuid4():
    """Generate a random UUID."""
    return UUID(bytes=os.urandom(16), version=4)
```

so from a standpoint of *how the randomness is generated*, these don't differ.