# What is the correct way of generating authorization token in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, uuid, auth-token

I'm trying to generate auth token in my django project.When i inspect source code of django-rest framework, they seem to generate auth_token using:-

```
binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()
```

but auth_token should be unique so that i can find corresponding user from auth_token.What is the best possible way of generating auth token, `uuid` or same as that of drf framework?

Comment: you can go with the DRF way, I don't see any problem with that, do you?

Comment: @JPG i think that it my generate two auth_token which are same. Point out, if i'm wrong

Comment: In short, they won't. see this post [Whats the difference between os.urandom() and random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514695/whats-the-difference-between-os-urandom-and-random)

Comment: see this also [Which one is more secure to use? uuid, binascii.hexlify(os.urandom()) or random.SystemRandom()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579156/which-one-is-more-secure-to-use-uuid-binascii-hexlifyos-urandom-or-random)